# Where can I remove a pickliist item in salutation picklist?

Tags: leads

By calling

```
binding.describeObjects(new string[] { "lead" });
```

I can see that the Salutation picklist for leads is

```
Field: Salutation
    Label: Salutation
    Type: picklist
    Length: 40
    Picklist values:
            Item: Mr.
            Item: Ms.
            Item: Mrs.
            Item: Dr.
            Item: Prof.
```

However, in an API call to add a lead using the partner WSDL, I specified a different salutation ("Test") and it was accepted and the lead's Salutation is set to Test.

Where in Salesforce can I remove this item from the Salutation picklist?

I have went

> > Setup > Objects and Fields > Object Manager > Leads

but under fields and relationships I do not see Salutation.

I have the Professional edition of Salesforce and my user profile type is Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklist fields are generally just text fields on the back end. You can specify any string you want. Some picklist fields are restricted so you can only select values enumerated in the metadata, but `Lead.Salutation` is not one of them. You can see for yourself in the describe information. There is no way to make a standard picklist field restricted.

```
system.assertEquals(false, Lead.Salutation.getDescribe().isRestrictedPicklist());
```

If you really want to restrict it to the values you already have set up, you will need to write a `Validation Rule` to enforce it. Note that it will not dynamically scale if you add any new values.

```
1 != CASE(Salutation,
    "Mr.", 1,
    "Ms.", 1,
    "Mrs.", 1,
    "Dr.", 1,
    "Prof.", 1,
    0
)
```

You could use a simpler formula if you're having difficulty wrapping your head around the above approach, but it does greatly increase the compile size:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Salutation__c, "Mr.")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Salutation__c, "Ms.")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Salutation__c, "Mrs.")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Salutation__c, "Dr.")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Salutation__c, "Prof."))
)
```

To add or remove values, click the `Edit` link next to the `Salutation` field (`Setup` > `Customize` > `Lead` > `Fields`).

[image: Lead Salutation]

Once you click that link, you will see a fairly intuitive interface to control the available values.

[image: Salutation Picklist Values]

Comment: Okay, but where in Salesforce can I edit the picklist items?

Comment: @andrewb just click `Edit` next to the field.

Comment: I had to change to classic Salesforce to see these options